# STSADM.EXE -o restore options

Tags: 2007, content-database, stsadm, migrate, database-server

I'm moving some moss databases from one database server to a new one.

I've been following the steps outlined in this [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.12).aspx#Section2)

On step **13. Restore an SSP to the new location.** I'm coming across some confusing options.

After I run the backup history command to get the backup ID, I run this stsadm command as per the article:

```
STSADM.EXE -o restore -directory \\share\spbackup -restoremethod new -backupid b272f2dd-c009-4f8e-9023-22f9ffe41323 -newdatabaseserver dbalias
```

Eventually, I start to get questions like these:

```
Change location/name for: Farm\SharedServices1\SharePoint - Webapp Name
Change location/name for: Farm\SharedServices1\SharePoint - Webapp Name\WSS_Content
```

I continue to get interrogated for things like the new database server name (do I put the alias? I already told the server to point to the new instance via cliconfg) and the location of the databases. Am I supposed to choose all the defaults?  If I choose the defaults for one of the dbs, it says it already exists.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to choose here.  That technet article just seems to skim right by those details. Is there a detailed / very specific guide to what I need to be choosing for each prompt given that I'm just trying to move my databases and I don't necessarily want to create / rename anything? (unless I have to)

Comment: You just moving the database then you using the stsadm restore, rahter simply use the sql backup and restore and mvoe the db to new sql server.

Comment: I ended up just creating a new SSP.